# Passing params from my frontend to backend in React isn't working. Is there another way to pass frontend variables to the backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parameters, frontend, backend

I have been building an app that displays information about famous actors. I created a small backend for my app in order to keep my API key safe. However, in order to make the necessary API get request, I need to be able to pass the actor name that is selected by the user as a parameter to the backend, but when I use the typical 'req.query' to declare the value, the call does not work. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Here is the frontend code:

```
const getInputValue = (event) => {
      setActor(event.target.value); 
  }; 

  const actorQuery = () => { 
      var axios = require('axios');

      var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:8000/actor-guess',
      params: {language: 'en-US', query: actor, page: '1', include_adult: 'false'}, 
    };

      axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data.results[0].id);
      setActorID(response.data.results[0].id); 
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
  };
```

Backend code:

```
const PORT = 8000; 
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.get('/actor-guess', (req, res) => {
  const actor = req.query.query <-- this is where I am trying to get the param from the front end, but it isn't working. 

  var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=' + process.env.REACT_API_KEY,
      params: {language: 'en-US', query: actor, page: '1', include_adult: 'false'}, 
      headers: { }
    };
    
    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
})
```

Comment: What is the value of `actor`, at the time `actorQuery` runs? Does it have a valid/expected value?

Comment: Yes, it is a value that is provided by the input of the user, but even when a valid string is provided, it doesn't work. I have also tried hard coding the value of actor to ensure that the issue isn't simply that the value isn't valid, but this didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried logging `req.query`?

Comment: I tried it and get this error: "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000".  I tried changing ports a bunch of times but the error continues to show up. It is also strange because the data from my other API calls display correctly on the port.